# Render 'edit' page test not working..not sure what else to try

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to get one of my tests to pass but I can't seem to get it:

```
Failures:
  1) UsersController PUT 'update' failure should render the 'edit' page
     Failure/Error: put :udpate, :id => @user, :user => @attr
     No route matches {:id=>#<User id: 1, name: "User_Name", email: "USER@gmail.com", created_at: "2011-05-29 03:26:30", updated_at: "2011-05-29 03:26:30", encrypted_password: "fc70fcb4b094b388d87c5054ed9b0bfa06f53431d44c527e852...", salt: nil>, :user=>{:email=>"", :name=>"", :password=>"", :password_confirmation=>""}, :controller=>"users", :action=>"udpate"}
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:164:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the code I am trying to get it to pass with in my UsersController:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: if you copied and pasted that code then update is mistyped on the put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr

Comment: wow...dyslexic for a second...sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests should look something like this...

```
describe "PUT 'update'" do
before do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  test_sign_in(@user)
end

describe "failure" do
  before do
    @attr = { :name => "", :email => "", :password => "", :password_confirmation => "" }
  end

  it "should render the 'edit' page" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    response.should render_template('users/edit')
  end

  it "should have the right title" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
  end

end

describe "success" do
  before do
    @attr = { :name => "Other User", :email => "other_user@example.com", :password => "barfoo", :password_confirmation => "barfoo" }
  end

  it "should change the users attributes" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :users => @attr
    user = assigns(:user)
    @user.reload
    @user.name.should == user.name
    @user.email.should == user.email
    @user.encrypted_password == user.encrypted_password
  end

  it "should have a flash message" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    flash[:success].should =~ /updated/
  end

end
```

Comment: can replace the before with:

    let(:attr) { ... }

means you don't need an @ variable